# How does (should) Kafka Consumer cope with Poison Messages

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

When a Kafka Consumer fails to deserialize a message, is it the client applications responsibility to deal with the Poison Message?

Or

Does Kafka "increment" the message offset and continue consumption of valid messages?

Is there a "Best Practice" for dealing with Poison Messages held on Kafka topics?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When Kafka is unable to deserialize the record the consumer will receive a `org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException`, you should commit the offset yourself and keep consuming.

Comment: Some users also opt to write any such poison messages to "quarantine" Kafka topics (i.e. normal Kafka topics, just special-purposed to only contain poison messages), where they can be e.g. inspected and reconstructed if possible.

Comment: Hi @miguno, how can you moved to another topic a message that you can't deserialize and is inside kafka?

Comment: Have you tried copying the data as-is, i.e. bit-by-bit (i.e. read both the key and the value as `byte[]`)?

Comment: But you are talking about reading the log file directly right? @miguno without using the kafka-api

Comment: If I commit the offset there, there is then no guarantee of retry of messages which are ahead in progressing and waiting to be manually committed. This is possible when using akka stream and alpakka kafka