# Why does Kafka Consumer keep receiving the same messages (offset)

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have a SOAP Web Service that sends a kafka request message and waits for a kafka response message (e.g. consumer.poll(10000)).

Each time the web service is called it creates a new Kafka Producer and a new Kafka Consumer.

every time I call the web service the consumer receives the same messages (e.g. messages with the same offset).

I am using Kafka 0.9 and have auto commit enabled and a auto commit frequency of 100 ms.

for each ConsumerRecord returned by the poll() method I process within its own  Callable, e.g.

```
ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(200);

for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records) {

final Handler handler = new Handler(consumerRecord);
            executor.submit(handler);

}
```

Why do I keep receiving the same messages over and over again?

**UPDATE 0001**

```
metric.reporters = []
metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
value.deserializer = class com.kafka.MDCDeserializer
group.id = group-A.group
partition.assignment.strategy = [org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RangeAssignor]
reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
max.partition.fetch.bytes = 1048576
bootstrap.servers = [machine1:6667, machine2:6667, machine3:6667, machine0:6667]
retry.backoff.ms = 100
sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
sasl.kerberos.service.name = kafka
sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
ssl.keystore.type = JKS
ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
enable.auto.commit = true
ssl.key.password = null
fetch.max.wait.ms = 500
sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
ssl.truststore.password = null
session.timeout.ms = 30000
metrics.num.samples = 2
client.id = 
ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = null
key.deserializer = class com.kafka.UUIDDerializer
ssl.protocol = TLS
check.crcs = true
request.timeout.ms = 40000
ssl.provider = null
ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
ssl.keystore.location = null
heartbeat.interval.ms = 3000
auto.commit.interval.ms = 5000
receive.buffer.bytes = 32768
ssl.cipher.suites = null
ssl.truststore.type = JKS
security.protocol = PLAINTEXTSASL
ssl.truststore.location = null
ssl.keystore.password = null
ssl.keymanager.algorithm = IbmX509
metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
fetch.min.bytes = 1024
send.buffer.bytes = 131072
auto.offset.reset = latest
```

Comment: Is it possible that you configure you kafka consumer to always start with a smallest offset?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the code that you are showing. I think your problem is that the new Consumer is single threaded. If you poll once and then don't do another poll then `auto.commit.offset` is not going to work.

Try putting your code in a while loop and see when you poll again the offset will be committed.

Comment: good spot!, once we made a loop to call poll multiple times it all started working as expected. Thanks very much for your time

Comment: no problem hector, if http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35991849/how-does-should-kafka-consumer-cope-with-poison-messages/35993439#35993439 was also helpful for you consider accepting it.